# How do I let a Nuxt page know the error code status?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am setting up a Nuxt site and would like to have some error handling (such as 404 and 401). I followed the guide on both the [Nuxt.js Website for Layouts](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/views/#error-page) as well as [This helpful video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AqhPwNBD9tM).

I have gotten it to the point where the error redirects to my Error page when entering an invalid link, however I cannot get the tutorials 'error.statuscode' to receive .

Both tutorials have a prop 'error', like so:

```js
// Nuxt.js site
props:[
        'error'
    ],
//video
props:{
     error:{
          type: Object,
          default: null
     }
}
```

thus allowing them to render errors like this:

```html
<div v-if="error.statuscode === 400">
...
</div>
<div v-else-if="error.statuscode === 404">
...
</div>
<div v-else>
...
</div>
```

I have tried making the page wait until 'error' is defined by wrapping the whole thing with 'v-f="error"', however that has not improved the situation.

This may be related, but Nuxt is also no longer throwing an error when navigating to "localhost:3000/does_not_exist"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a little mistake:

it should be

> **error.statusCode**

So you can change your code like below:

```
    <div v-if="error.statusCode === 404">
      {{ pageNotFound }}
    </div>
    <div v-else>
    ...
    </div>
```

Comment: Of all the bloody things, it's the camelCase